# Dropdownlist Default value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

There's a pair of ddlists on my WebUserControl. In My Page_Load code I have typed:

```
ddlDay.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Day", "0"));
    ddlMonth.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Month", "0"));

    CatalogAccess ca = new CatalogAccess();
    ddlStudents.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
    ddlStudents.DataSource = ca.GetStudents();
    ddlStudents.DataTextField = "FullName";
    ddlStudents.DataValueField = "UserID";
    ddlStudents.DataBind();
```

It works good to these ddl which are not databined. This one >

```
ddlStudents.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
```

doesnt work at all. Every time  I am getting just the names of the students. How to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` on your `ddlStudents` dropdown.

Comment: @Nathan: be sure to use the green checkbox to mark the 'best answer'! It's part of the reputation system at StackOverflow.

Comment: Oops! I am new here. Where's the box?

Comment: Ok got it! reputation is save!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should also be able to move the insert of the blank row after the databind.

```
ddlDay.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Day", "0"));
ddlMonth.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Month", "0"));

CatalogAccess ca = new CatalogAccess();
ddlStudents.DataSource = ca.GetStudents();
ddlStudents.DataTextField = "FullName";
ddlStudents.DataValueField = "UserID";
ddlStudents.DataBind();
ddlStudents.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can through the collection of Students that ca.GetStudents() returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlStudents" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Text="Choose" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```